# routers and the HDLC protocol

Tags: networking

I'm training in computer networks, I hope my question won't be stupid... Are routers involved in the HDLC protocol, and therefore at layer 2 of the OSI model?
I always thought that routers only intervene at layer 3 of the OSI model, and the HDLC protocol happens at layer 2, so I'm a little lost...

thank you for your reply !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routers route packets at layer-3, but they are still hosts that require layer-1 connections and layer-2 protocols.

Remember that you must have connections to a router at layer-1 (serial, ethernet, Wi-Fi, token ring, etc.), and there must be layer-2 protocols to transfer the layer-3 packet on the connections.

A router receiving a layer-2 frame will strip off the frame to get the layer-3 packet. It will then route the layer-3 packet to the next interface based on the layer-3 addressing, and it will build a new layer-2 frame for the new interface.

Comment: OK thanks ! I think I didn't understand the logic very well, but it's coming little by little!!! THANKS